# EF Frustration mapping a view to an object

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-4.1

I have a table that hold records of part numbers for a specific project like so:

```
create table ProjectParts
    (
    PartNumber varchar(20) not null,
    ProjectID int not null,
    Description varchar(max) not null,
    primary key nonclustered (PartNumber, ProjectID)
    );
```

I have a view that will collect inventory information from multiple places, but for now I basically have a skeleton:

```
create view ProjectQuantities as
select distinct
    pp.PartNumber,
    pp.ProjectID,
    0 as QtyOnHand,
    0 as QtyOnOrder,
    0 as QtyCommitted
from
    ProjectParts pp;
```

So far, so good.  I go into EF designer in Visual Studio (I already had an object model using the ProjectParts table) and update the model from the database.  I select the ProjectQuantities view, click ok.

EF tries to divine the key on the table as a combination of all columns, but I fix that so the key for the object is the `PartNumber` and `ProjectID` columns.  I check to make sure this validates, and it does.

Next, I add an 1:1 association between the ProjectPart object and the ProjectQuantity object in the EF UI and click OK.  Now, when I try validating, I get the message `Error 11008: Association 'ProjectQuantityProjectPart' is not mapped.`  Seriously?  It can't figure this out?  Alright, I select the link, go to the Mapping Details, and add the ProjectParts table.  It adds both tables and meshes up the key relationships.  My job is done.  I run the validation.

No luck for me.  Now I get the error `Error 3021: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line (line number): Each of the following columnes in table ProjectParts is mapped to multiple conceptual side properties`.  The the message lists the ProjectID and the PartNumber columns and their references to the association I just created.

Well duh! Of course there are multiple references! it's a 1:1 compound key, it has to have multiple references!

This is stopping me from getting stuff done.  Does anyone know a simple way to fix this so I can collect Quantity information when I'm collecting data about a project and its parts?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to remove "distinct", each raw is guaranteed to be unique by the primary key constraint.

Comment: I tried that first; I only added the distinct to see if that would help EF figure out the keys better.

Comment: EF does not try  to figure out keys from views, because Views are models that are outside of the physical database schema.  If you want the views to map, you have to do everything manually.  They're essentially treated as stand-alone objects, and are even read-only by default.

Comment: OK that's fine, but surely you should be able to create object associations with them?  Otherwise what's the point to EF even bringing them in?

Comment: @Jeremy - Let me rephrase.  EF assumes all non-null fields are keys in a view.  This is because a view is basically a pre-compiled query like a stored proc.  EF would have to reverse engineer the sql used to create the view to figure out the real keys, and that's way beyond its scope.  Yes, you can create linkages to views, but you must maintain them manually.  You can't expect EF to figure them out the way it does for the physical model.  So my point was that you shouldn't get frustrated that EF can't figure out your views keys.  It's simply not part of what it does.

Comment: I assumed it was something like that.  My frustration was not so much in the fact that it could not figure out the key (although I was a bit miffed that it "guessed" and got it wrong... how about asking, instead?), but in the fact that it would not let me create associations without a cryptic error message.  If I define the key, and it matches perfectly with an entity that has a key of the exact same signature and it's a 1:1 relationship, that should be all the info it needs to know to get it to work properly (IMHO).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may find this article useful http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2011/01/31/Building-an-Entity-Framework-40-model-on-views-practical-tips.aspx

Comment: thanks!  I'll read through this and see how it applies.  It looks like this might be crucial info.

Comment: I found an alternative to what I was planning based on that article.  Thanks, that's good info.